# Losing reference to DOM elements after I clone them

Tags: javascript, mootools

Using MooTools, I'm caching some DOM elements in variables when the DOM is ready, like so:

```
var mc = $('main-content'),
    bg = $('bg'),
    arrows = $$('arrows');
```

Both `bg` and `arrows` are located within the `mc` DOM element. I want to clone the `mc` node, perform some operations on it and then insert the clone into the DOM:

```
function updateDOM (parent) {
    var parentID = parent.id,
        oldNode = document.getElementById(parentID),
        clone = oldNode.cloneNode(true);

    // work with clone

    oldNode.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, oldNode);

}
```

When I run `updateDOM(mc)`, I find that any other subsequent functions that would change `mc`, `bg`, or `arrows` don't work. When I do console.log() the elements, they show up, but they don't reflect any of the changes that have been made since their initialization.

Considering that I'm cloning the element, it makes sense to me that `mc` no longer references `div#main-content`. `updateDOM()` is a function that could be used by any element. Do I really need to hard code a way to re-instantiate each variables that I cache or is there a more dynamic way of doing this?

Comment: Your caching code looks incorrect... did you mean to put `#` in front of the selectors?  Or is this not jQuery?

Comment: @Jacob: No; it looks like Prototype (`$$`)

Comment: MooTools to be exact, which I have added to the question. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
> function updateDOM (parent) {
>     var parentID = parent.id,
>         oldNode = document.getElementById(parentID),
>         clone = oldNode.cloneNode(true);
```

Maybe I'm thick, but it seems to me that the above function is passed an element reference that is assigned to *parent*. It then uses `getElementById(parent.id)` to get a reference to the same element, then clone it. How is this different to:

```
function updateDOM (parent) {
    var clone = parent.cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: When I was playing around with the function, I noticed that I was having issues with the approach you described. Using document.getElementById seemed to work where the other approach didn't. I didn't look too much into it at the time so I couldn't say why.

Answer (score 0):

Change `updateDOM` to return the new, cloned node, and just change your calls to `updateDOM` to also reassign the variable.

```
mc = updateDOM(mc);
```

Comment: What about the other cached elements, like bg and arrows which reside in the mc element? Since they reside in mc when updateDOM is used, I'm losing reference to them as well.

Comment: Ah. Didn't notice that wrinkle. Other than just directly modifying your elements instead of cloning and replacing, I don't see any easier or more efficient alternative to re-selecting the elements.